# no matches for kind "Replicaset" in version "apps/v1"?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, devops, minikube

[Please click here for the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxnEI.png)I'm trying to configure a replicaset for my podspec file in my minikube. My minikube version: v1.26.1. I couldn't figure, whether the issue is with my code or api resources.

this is my error: resource mapping not found for name: "my-replicaset" namespace: "" from "replicasets.yaml": no matches for kind "Replicaset" in version "apps/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first

tried to change the apps/v1 to some thing else; nothing works!

Comment: You should use Deployments to manage ReplicaSets rather then creating replicaSet yourself

Answer (score 0):

It’s Replica**S**et … (capital S).

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake but the error is different